# Error when replacing part of raster with another raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

When using Con(IsNull("replacement_raster"), "full_raster", "replacement_raster") to replace parts of a larger raster with a new smaller raster I get stripes in the vicinity of the smaller raster extent (See attached image). My best guess is that some potential NoData interfere. What could be the solution to get rid of the stripe?

I have set the processing extent to the larger raster as well.

Comment: Expand small raster first, type "small" in raster calculator.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean with type "small". I assume I need to have the smaller raster in the same extent as the larger raster, but with NoData where values are missing. But how do I set up the conditional statement for this?

Comment: Well, I managed to remove the stripe with defining NoData for both raster as the same value and verifying that projection was the same for both rasters. Wouldn't using processing extent as the larger raster recognize "values" around the smaller raster as NoData?